# Get Product ID By Product Name (Escape Special Characters)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In Wordpress after checkout I need to get product ID by the product Name. Currently I am using:

```
$mini = get_page_by_title( $mini_name, OBJECT, 'product' );
```

It works fine. But sometimes the products can have special characters such as ' % ,

example of products with special characters:
Gordon’s Premium Pink Gin 5cl
Bakewell Cherry & Almond Gin 5cl
Grey Goose L’Orange Vodka 5cl

How can I get an ID of these products?

Comment: At first sight I would not use `get_page_by_title()` to obtain a product ID after checkout but as more (clear) information is missing about what you are trying to achieve I can refer you to [get_page_by_title() not working if special characters are present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190629/get-page-by-title-not-working-if-special-characters-are-present), maybe another option is to use the product SKU or product slug instead..

Comment: So Basically the product name comes from a different product meta. I use that product meta to get the product name -> Use the name to get product ID -> Use Product ID to add the product to the order. What way would you do this?

Comment: Using html_entity_decode($mini_name) Almost works. the & sign now pulls through so works for the bakewell cherry but still not for Gordon's because of the '